# EditorFor для коллекции

Tags: c#, mvc, коллекции, razor

Добрый день.

У меня есть несколько объектов, таблица техники, с связью Child-Parent внутри таблицы (ссылается сам на себя)

```
public class Technic
{
    //Это Идишник
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    //тут указана ссылка на запись внутри таблицы техники
    public Guid? ParentId {get;set;}
    //Если запись Parent установлено на true
    public bool IsParent {get;set;}

}
```

и основная модель пусть будет Парковка

```
public class Parking
{
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

[UIHint("Technic")]
public List<Technic> ParkingTechnic{get;set;}
}
```

итак, у меня есть контроллер

```
public ActionResult ParkingAdd(){
var model = new Parking(){Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Name="Тест"};
//добавим категории
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Категория1", IsParent = true});
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Категория2", IsParent = true});
//добавим технику
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Техника1", IsParent = false, ParentId=model.ParkingTechnic.First(l=>l.Name == ""Категория1"").Id});
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Техника2", IsParent = false, ParentId=model.ParkingTechnic.First(l=>l.Name == ""Категория1"").Id});
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Техника3", IsParent = false, ParentId=model.ParkingTechnic.First(l=>l.Name == ""Категория1"").Id});
//Добавим технику к второй категории
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Техника4", IsParent = false, ParentId=model.ParkingTechnic.First(l=>l.Name == ""Категория2"").Id});
model.ParkingTechnic.Add(new Technic(){Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Техника5", IsParent = false, ParentId=model.ParkingTechnic.First(l=>l.Name == ""Категория2"").Id});

return View(model)
}
```

**Вот вьюшка**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)

//Отправим список в шаблон
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ParkingTechnic)
```

**А вот шаблон**

```
@model List<Technic>

@{
for (int i = 0; i> model.count(); i++){
@Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Count)
@html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].ArrivalTime)
}
}
```

В таком раскладе, он выплёвывает мне все записи из коллекции техники.
Вопрос как заставить его вывести категории в качестве надписи и под ними сгруппированную технику

- Категория1

  - Техника1 - поле ввода даты и количества
  - Техника2 - поле ввода даты и количества
  - Техника3 - поле ввода даты и количества
- Категория2

  - Техника4 - у этой техники вторая категория, поле ввода и даты
  - Техника5 - поле ввода и даты

Comment: Вы хотите только отобразить `List<Technic>` или нужна возможность отправить изменения на сервер?

Comment: на данный момент я хочу сделать форму, детали по обьекту я буду генерировать по другому шаблону. Так что да, мне нужен Editor для отправки данных на сервер. Сейчас я это решил, правда довольно грубо и муторно. Отсортировкой в последовательности, а потом отрисовкой по порядку, с проверкой. Но не эллегантно. . .